# Не могу установить oracle database на ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, oracle

Здравствуйте уважаемое комьюнити!

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой при установке oracle-xe-universal (v.10) на ubuntu (v.14.04.03). Во время установки валятся ошибки в терминале и, после окончания установки и конфигурирования, нельзя зайти на страничку localhost:8081/apex, а также получить коннект к базе через IDE. Через PL/SQL "connect sys as sysdba" коннектится, но всё равно не работает - на все команды даёт ответ "2".

Ниже прикрепил лог терминала.

Пожалуйста, помогите решить эту проблему или хотя бы подскажите, в какую "сторону" стоит глядеть?

```
victori@victori-EP43-S3L:~$ sudo apt-get install oracle-xe-universal
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
НОВЫЕ пакеты, которые будут установлены:
  oracle-xe-universal:i386
обновлено 0, установлено 1 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 31 пакетов не обновлено.
Необходимо скачать 0 B/262 MB архивов.
После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 451 MB.
ВНИМАНИЕ: Следующие пакеты невозможно аутентифицировать!
  oracle-xe-universal:i386
Установить эти пакеты без проверки? [y/N] y
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета oracle-xe-universal.
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 295829 файлов и каталогов.)
Preparing to unpack …/oracle-xe-universal_10.2.0.1-1.1_i386.deb ...
expr: синтаксическая ошибка
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: строка 63: [: -lt: ожидается использование унарного оператора
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: строка 71: [: -gt: ожидается использование унарного оператора
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: строка 82: [: -gt: ожидается использование унарного оператора
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: строка 93: [: -gt: ожидается использование унарного оператора
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: строка 110: [: -gt: ожидается использование унарного оператора
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: строка 135: [: -lt: ожидается использование унарного оператора
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: строка 141: [: -lt: ожидается использование унарного оператора
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: строка 147: [: -lt: ожидается использование унарного оператора
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: строка 152: [: -lt: ожидается использование унарного оператора
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: строка 167: [: 18446744073692774399: ожидается числовое выражение
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: строка 179: [: 18446744073692774399: ожидается числовое выражение
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: строка 211: [: -lt: ожидается использование унарного оператора
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: строка 217: [: -gt: ожидается использование унарного оператора
Unpacking oracle-xe-universal (10.2.0.1-1.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Настраивается пакет oracle-xe-universal (10.2.0.1-1.1) …
update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/oracle-xe missing LSB information
update-rc.d: see 
Executing Post-install steps...

(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
You must run '/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure' as the root user to configure the database.

Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
victori@victori-EP43-S3L:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure

Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Configuration
-------------------------------------------------
This will configure on-boot properties of Oracle Database 10g Express 
Edition.  The following questions will determine whether the database should 
be starting upon system boot, the ports it will use, and the passwords that 
will be used for database accounts.  Press  to accept the defaults. 
Ctrl-C will abort.

Specify the HTTP port that will be used for Oracle Application Express [8080]:8081

Specify a port that will be used for the database listener [1521]:1521

Specify a password to be used for database accounts.  Note that the same
password will be used for SYS and SYSTEM.  Oracle recommends the use of 
different passwords for each database account.  This can be done after 
initial configuration:
Confirm the password:

Do you want Oracle Database 10g Express Edition to be started on boot (y/n) [y]:y

Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done
Configuring Database...Done
Starting Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Instance...Done
Installation Completed Successfully.
To access the Database Home Page go to "http://127.0.0.1:8081/apex"
```

Comment: */var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: строка 63: [: -lt: ожидается использование унарного оператора* — очень кривыми руками собран этот пакет. подозреваю, что и с его удалением у вас проблемы возникнут.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, у Oracle вообще очень недружелюбный установкщик.

Comment: А под системным пользователем под которым вы запускаете sqlplus установлены переменные среды (посмотреть по `set`) ORACLE_BASE, ORACLE_HOME и есть ли в переменной PATH пути до ораклового каталога bin ?

Comment: @LEQADA, мне почему-то представляется более вероятным, что происхождение упомянутого в вопросе файла с пакетом не имеет к *oracle* никакого отношения. ну не до такой же степени в *oracle* криворуки!

Comment: @LEQADA Недружелюбный мягко сказано, он готовый пакет ставил и то напоролся, а когда ставишь полный ... лично мне приходилось на определенных этапах установки править Makefile'ы на ходу. Я почти уверен, что там база боле менее пондялась, только чуть где то что то подправить. только вот хз чем помочь

Comment: @alexanderbarakin К сожалению подобное поведение мне сразу показывает, что это установщик оракла. Они могли чуть под другой системой тестировать, у разработчиков оракловых установщиков очень своеобразный вкус по шеллам, под которыми это должно работать. Думаю в данном случае надо попробовать угадать каким шеллом должен быть /bin/sh

Comment: Вот, нашел описание на сайте убунту, попробуйте установить переменные окружения как они пишут https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle10g   может быть sql-plus заработает, а тогда уже можно будет думать о том что с этим дальше делать ...

Comment: Спасибо всем кто обратил внимание. Мне помогли эти комментарии. Проблема решалась ручным запуском /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/bin/tnslsnr, причём не без бубна. Запускаю c sudo. К 127.0.0.1:8081/apex доступ появляется и через IDE тоже. Не сказать, что идеально (: P), но главное работает, а мне это сейчас очень нужно. Позже постараюсь разобраться с этой проблемой по серьёзнее. Ещё раз спасибо за советы.

Answer (score 1):

из комментария:

---

Проблема решалась ручным запуском `/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/bin/tnslsnr`, причём не без бубна. Запускаю c sudo.

К `127.0.0.1:8081/apex` доступ появляется, и через IDE тоже. Не сказать, что идеально (: P), но главное работает, а мне это сейчас очень нужно.